# Cannot hear sound through the VSTi in Reaper

Tags: reaper, virtual-instruments

I am running `Reaper` through `Wine` on Ubuntu. I can import a music file and it plays normally. I then close that track.

Then I do: `Insert` -> `Virtual instrument on new track...` -> choose `VSTi: ReaSynth (Cockos)` This opens a dialog for FX on the track which I close. I then have a track which says `ReaSynth`. I then go to `View` -> `Virtual MIDI Keyboard` and a keyboard pops up. I press the keys on the keyboard and the levels on the `MASTER` track oscillate, and so does the levels on the control for the track1 (ReaSynth), but **no** sound is heard. The track is not muted. For the track I have the input on channel 1 and then i put it on all channels as well.

Am I missing something that must be set up?

Comment: I had a similar question [here](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/1109/how-do-i-configure-midi-in-reaper).  Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Unlike most other things is Reaper, `ReaSynth` is almost completely useless. It's quite possible that you _do_ get sound, but it's inaudible (e.g. too low frequency, to soft) because the synth is set up badly. Have you tried other `VSTi`s already?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, that was exactly it! Could you post it as an answer? Why is it so bad, and what do you recommend as alternatives? It would be great to put that into an answer.

Comment: It's not bad, it's just very primitive. There are thousands of different synthesizer plugins, which are good for you depends on what kind of sounds you'd like.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, thanks, if you put that as an answer so I could accept it that would be great. and a few words on going about choosing a plugin would be also appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I have just installed Reaper today, I loaded a vsti and selected my midi keyboard but no sound was coming out of it when I played but when I pressed record and listened to what was recorded I could hear the music. I noticed that there was a "Record monitoring" button (see the pictures below). I clicked it, pressed a key and I was able to hear what I was playing.

**Record monitoring OFF**

[image: **Record monitoring OFF**]

**Record monitoring ON**

[image: **Record monitoring ON**]